# How to route to auxiliary route programmatically with param

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have a component that receives an event from a child component, like so:

```html
<my-component (dataOutput)="route($event)"></my-component>
```

In my function `route` I would like to route to a url that contains the URL I'm currently on, PLUS the auxiliary route which shows an overlay with some data received by the output event. I've attempted the below which doesn't work

```
const url = ['albums', albumId];
const outlet = { outlets: { artistEditor: ['artist', artistId] } }
this.router.navigate(url, outlet);
```

If I route to just `{ outlets: { artistEditor: ['artist', artistId] } }`, the application cannot find the route. Although, as a side note, if I wrote it in HTML it navigates correctly with a test button like so:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { artistEditor: ['artist', 'artistId'] } }]" >New</a>
```

What's the best way to programmatically route to an auxiliary route, ensuring the URL that I defined is also adhered to?

Comment: so `router.navigate([{ outlets: { artistEditor: ['artist', artistId] } }]);` doesn't work?

Comment: Hey Nathan - That's correct. The following error fires in the console: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'artist/id'" - The correct ID appears at least.

Comment: could you give a small reproducible example in stackblitz

Comment: Unfortunately probably not. There are a few moving parts with child components (referenced in the main post) that I'd probably take longer setting it up to match haha. Not sure how the HTML on the same page can link correctly, but the typescript can't.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by using `navigateByUrl`

````
const url = ['albums', albumId];
const routeWithAux = url + ('(artistEditor:artist/' + artistId + ')');
this.router.navigateByUrl(routeWithAux);
    ```
````